# Knockout select bindings overwriting my predefined observable object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i have a application which data is passed from one page to another with predefined data objects/arrays assigned to it, my issue is i can see the `observableArray` having a value and then it turns the `SelectedPeople` observable to undefined.

I have eliminated down to the data bind markup as when i remove that my observable array does not set anything to undefined.

Here is how i am binding my observables/observableArray to the elements.

```
<select data-bind="options: ObservableArray.People, value: ObservableArray.SelectedPeople, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

- `ObservableArray.People` = Observable Array of objects - works fine and renders all the dropdown options
- `ObservableArray.SelectedPeople` = Observable

Both have the 'Name' object defined to match the `optionsText`. It works perfectly when selecting data from scratch but when i try have predefined data in it the `Observable.SelectedPeople` object keeps getting sent as `undefined` when it tries to load.

Basically my `Observable.SelectedPeople` has a object on that which should predefined the value of that select and the object 100% matches one of the dropdown `ObservableArray.People` options. I need it not to set `Observable.SelectedPeople` to undefined and populate the select box.

Can anyone see why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: You should check out the value that is assigned to the `Observable.SelectedPeople` after you select a value from the dropdown. That value should be a `property` defined in the objects bound to the dropdown. You should be pushing the value of that property to `Observable.SelectedPeople`.

Comment: Observable.SelectedPeople has a default value which should populate the Observable.People to the one which is set.. @gkb

Comment: Look at this post and see how the `optionsValue` attribute has been used in the select control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587230/knockout-bind-a-key-value-object-to-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

> ...and the object 100% matches one of the dropdown `ObservableArray.People` options.

This line makes me suspicious of whether you're using an actual *reference* to the object, or just an object that is *similar*.

For example, this will **not** work:

```
var options = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3}];
var selectedOption = ko.observable({ id: 1 });
```

Knockout does not perform some sort of `deepEquals` comparison; if it sees a non-primitive, it does a reference check. `options[0] !== { id: 1 }`, so this initial selection is **not** valid.

The code below **will** work, because you're using an actual object from the array you use in your select element:

```
var options = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3}];
var selectedOption = ko.observable(options[0]);
```